# Oracle sql - ORA-00907 and my incorrect syntax

Tags: oracle, parentheses, ora-00907

I cannot figure out the syntax issue with the following code. When I run it, I get error

> *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*

Can anyone point out my flaw please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW LATESTAPPLICATIONS AS 
SELECT *
FROM application_history
WHERE entry_time IN
    (SELECT entry_time
    FROM application_history
    GROUP BY application_number; )
ORDER BY entry_number;​
```

Here is the table definition for `application_history`. I ideally want to only view application numbers with the latest time-stamps.

```
 CREATE TABLE  "APPLICATION_HISTORY" 
   (    "ENTRY_NUMBER" NUMBER(28,0), 
"APPLICATION_NUMBER" NUMBER(16,0) CONSTRAINT "APP_NUM_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ACTIVE" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "ACTIVE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"STATUS" VARCHAR2(40) DEFAULT 'APPLICATION ENTERED' CONSTRAINT "STATUS_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DATE_APPROVED" DATE, 
"DATE_APPLIED" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE CONSTRAINT "DATE_APPLIED_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ENTRY_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
 CONSTRAINT "ENTRY_NUM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENTRY_NUMBER")
USING INDEX  ENABLE
 )
```

Comment: You have a `;` in middle of your query. Should close as a typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semi-colon at the last but 1 line. `GROUP BY application_number; )` Remove it and you should be fine.

Semi-colon acts as the query terminator in Oracle, as you had placed it before the ) Oracle could not find it.

Comment: when i remove the semicolon, i get the error:
    ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @IamPancakeMan do you still face the issue? You will need 1 semi-colon at the end